# Anthurium discoloring leaves and browning stem

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, leaves, indoors

I have my anthurium repotted and after a while I see that the leaves have developed yellowish spots and the stem is becoming brown at the surface.
I water it using the saucer under the plant. Also have it near the window for indirect sunlight. The temp is also around 25-26 C in the room. I also have a humidifier that I use for them daily or every other day for around half an hour.
The soil is mix of perlite and normal soil. At the bottom and on top I have put some leca balls.
Is there any solution?
[image]

[image]